# Nesting :after of :last-child with LESS

Tags: css, less

Using LESS I need to remove an :after property within an element's :last-child.

```
li {
    &:after {
        content: '/';
    }
    &:last-child {
        &:after {
            content: '';
        }
    }
}
```

This is obviously not correct nesting - what am I missing?

Answer (score 20, accepted):

It looks correct to me, but if it's not working then try not nesting that second `:after`:

```
li {
    &:after {
        content: '/';
    }
    &:last-child:after {
        content: '';
    }
}
```

If you mean that the `:after` pseudo-element still displays for the last child, then you'll definitely want to change `content: '';` to `content: none;` instead. An empty string will still cause an empty box to be generated, while `none` generates *no* box.

Answer (score 1):

You can use also:

```
li {
&:not(:last-child):after {
    content: " | ";

  }
}
```